# Users activity 'counter' as icons near to the score

Tags: discussion, information-display

> I wish all stackoverflow have near to
>   the score a similar score with icons
>   thats shows the activity of the user
>   the last 30 days.

For example **if a user have done nothing the last month** or have done very few thinks near to the score **I wish to see an icon that shows thats.**

**If a user have many activity the last 30 days**, give many answers, make comments etc, I like to see near the score a diferent icon (maybe a raising star).

Why thats ? maybe **its a motivation for people**, maybe its **a way to see if you can get quick answer from some one**, maybe its **a way that even if you do not get votes but you are active** here to see something cool near your name.

Anyway this is an idea that I have from the first time I see stackoverflow.

Thank you for :)

Comment: I do not understand why you down vote with out say why - anything.

Comment: +1 I think that the 'user summary' (mailbox/name/rep/badges) section in the header could be usefully extended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how useful this would be.

For new questions, those who respond and answer are obviously active.

For old questions, why is it relevant if the information was added by someone who was active in the last 30 days? If the information is useful it doesn't exactly go stale, and if it has, then we hope that you have 2k rep and can edit the information to make it less stale.

Comment: @Jeff ok I agree with what you say. How about say that way: Something similar with the stat page. People that get to the first 20 answers or what ever you may think, why not get an icon near them to symbolize that are "active" the last days, work a lot here etc... -even as a motivation only-...